# How do I make an extension that runs code in VS code?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, typescript, visual-studio-code, custom-code

I have made an interpreted language using python. It works fine inside of the terminal but I'm struggling to find any resources/documentation on how to create an extension that can run it inside of the VS code IDE. I also would like to implement syntax highlighting for my language. The extension that I want to make would be similar to the "Python" VS code extension. (I AM NOT ASKING FOR RECOMMENDATIONS!)

Comment: you are running an interpreter inside an interpreter, do you have some performance left? Read up on writing a language extension.

Comment: I have read up on a language extensions but running code is poorly documented. Yes I have performance, in fact my language is actually pretty fast for being dual interpreted. Around the same speed as python itself. I have optimized it.

Comment: you don't run it inside VSC, and VSC is NOT an IDE, it is an editor with benefits. VSC just generates a terminal command and executes it in the integrated terminal. If you want to be able to debug your code in VSC you have to support the Debugger API

Comment: How would I do that, and do you have any suggestions for another IDE to do this in?

Comment: supporting the Debugger API is quite some work but it is documented in the VSC docs. But you have to write a debugger for your language.

Comment: The documentation on it is pretty confusing and very strange. Also will the debugger run the code?

Comment: The docs are kinda very referential but it always helps to see the code of similar extensions. Check this "live extension" https://github.com/xirider/livecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Microsoft documentation on how to build, debug and publish a [Visual Studio Code Extension.](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) I know you said Visual Studio Code, but you also said IDE, so I included this link to the [Visual Studio IDE Extension](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/extend/) in case you actually meant that instead of code.

Here is a [step by step VS Code youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srwsnNhiqv8) from good teacher, Traversy.

Congrats on your project, and Good luck.

Comment: I'll check it out and come back to you later, Thanks!